# Passport throwing "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

This is my first time using passport.

I keep getting this error when I try to launch my app:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/drewwyatt/Sites/JS/Node/MWInternal/app.js:38:14)
```

Here's the (relevant) portions of app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').LocalStrategy;

var app = express();
var connectionString = '***************';


// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// passport config
var Account = require('./models/account');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

mongoose.connect(connectionString);

var routes = require('./routes');

...
```

**/models/account.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Account = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').LocalStrategy;
```

to

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

The `passport-local` module [exports](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/index.js#L15) `Strategy`:

```
var Strategy = require('./strategy');
exports.Strategy = Strategy;
```

Comment: Just found the source code is:  `module.exports = Strategy;`  in passport-local v1.0.0, not sure if it has changed.